# completion of measure space, smallest sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $(X, \overline{\Omega}, \overline{\mu}$), where $\overline{\Omega} := \{ E \subseteq X |\exists A,B \in \Omega, A \subseteq E \subseteq B, \mu(A \backslash B)=0 \}$, $\overline{\mu} (E) = \mu(A)$ is the completion of the measure space $(X,\Omega,\mu)$.

I've already shown that $\overline{\Omega}$ is $\sigma$-algebra, but I got stuck showing that it's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\Omega$. Can somebody help me out there?

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$- algebra, then it is the smallest $\sigma$- algebra containing $\Omega$? You just need to check that $\bar{\Omega}$ is a $\sigma$- algebra.

Comment: But doesn't $\overline{\Omega}$ have to be the intersection of all complete $\sigma$-algebras that contain $\Omega$? Why does this hold?

Comment: Depends on your definition.